# LINQ for System.Collections.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

LINQ `Where()` works with `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` but cant be used if the implemented interface is `System.Collections.IEnumerable`

My question is, why is that so?

**Update:** 
Maybe a little bit of context, I want to use `.Where()` on the `Transform` class of Unity, which implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable` instead of `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Transform>` even though it only has `Transforms` as children..
So I now created an extension method for `Transform`, feel free to use it:

```
/// <summary> Where-Filter implementation for transform to filter out specific children</summary>
public static IEnumerable<GameObject> WhereChild(this Transform s, Func<GameObject, bool> callback) {
    List<GameObject> r = new List<GameObject>();
    foreach (Transform cur in s) { if (callback(cur.gameObject)) { r.Add(cur.gameObject); } }
    return r;
}
```

(Modify it if you want to work on the transforms and not the children Gameobjects instead, I like it more this way;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because most of those methods are generic and make little sense when you only get `object`s. A few methods *are* in fact declared as extension methods on `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`, e.g. `Cast<T>()` and `OfType<T>`, both of which return a typed enumerable.

So in your case you can use `Cast<object>()` to reap the benefits of LINQ in the most useless manner, because the predicate for `Where` cannot really reasonably do much with an `object` without casting it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Non generic collections where you can't really say anything about items more that they are just `object`s won't let you write useful predicates. And these are required by linq operators.

Suppose

```
IEnumerable e = ...;

e.Where( item => ?? );
```

Here `item` is of type `object` and you are pretty much stuck.

On the other hand

```
IEnumerable<Person> e = ...;

e.Where( item => ?? );
```

Here you can refer to whatever members the actual type contains.

Note that you can always "upcast" collections

```
IEnumerable e = ...;

e.OfType<Person>().Where( ... )
```

The `OfType` operator makes a generic collection of these items of a non generic collection that are of given type. Thus it allows you to introduce strong typing and use typed operators further the line.